# Numpy, 1:M joins on Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I was wondering if there is a way to join an numpy array.

Example:

```
array1 = [[1,c,d], [2,a,b], [3, e,f]]
array2 = [[2,g,g,t], [1,alpha, beta, gamma], [1,t,y,u], [3,dog, cat, fish]]
```

I need to join these array, but the Numpy documentation says if the records are not unique, the functions will fail or return unknown results.

Does anyone have any sample to do a `1:M` join instead of a `1:1` join on numpy arrays? Also, I know my examples are in the proper numpy format, but it's just to give a general idea.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "join". Stack them horizontally or vertically? Can you give the desired output? Also, your arrays have different dimensions (3x3 vs 4x4), so most "joining" will not work without adjusting their sizes.

Comment: Nils, What I mean is this.  Think of each array as a table, and I need to join Column 1 in array 1 with Column2 in array 2.  I know they are differing sizes, but that's what I think makes this interesting.  Also I want to ensure that the joined array (call it array3) contains all the data from array two.  This would mean that there would be two row entries for [1,c,d] from array1. Example [1,c,d,alpha, beta,gamma] and [1,c,d,t,y,u].

Comment: I would say you should use `list`s instead of `numpy.array`s then. Arrays are not made for this.

Comment: Nils, I think you are right.  I will have to convert the arrays into lists and then do what was shown below.  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are willing to achieve looks more like a new nested list based on your two input arrays.

Treating them as lists:

```
list1 = [[1,'c','d'], [2,'a','b'], [3, 'e','f']]
list2 = [[2,'g','g','t'], [1,'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'], [1,'t','y','u'], [3,'dog', 'cat', 'fish']]
```

You can build your desired result doing:

```
result = [i+j[1:] for i in list1 for j in list2 if i[0]==j[0]]
```

Which will look like this:

```
[[1, 'c', 'd', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'],
 [1, 'c', 'd', 't', 'y', 'u'],
 [2, 'a', 'b', 'g', 'g', 't'],
 [3, 'e', 'f', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish']]
```